# Safari homepage hijacked and I can't change back

Tags: macos, safari

imac 2011 10.10.5

Safari had homepage hijacked and I can't change it back to google.com.  When I go to Safari preferences and try and change, it just immediately goes to www.rack-search.com/....

I tried deleting all the com.apple.safari.plists in library.

Can you help?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not for a malware hijack situation, but rather a bug in Safari 11.0 that does not allow you to change the homepage. If you try to change the homepage, as soon as you defocus from that field, it reverts back to the original.

The workaround is:

- Enter the new homepage. Do not press tab/enter or leave the field.
- Click on another tab in Preferences, such as the Advanced tab.

Now it should ask you to confirm to change your homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you appear to have adware.  There's a free program the Apple Store and Apple Phone support even recommends called MalwareBytes. The website is adwaremedic.com.  Once you run it, you'll probably need to reboot and again reset your browser home page.

Comment: I installed and ran MBAM.  I also trashed some malware programs that were installed.  Anything else I can do to get my homepage back?

Comment: What page is your browser redirecting you to?

Comment: www.rack-search.com/....

Answer (score 1):

***Here is how I manually fix Safari***

**Remove Safari’s configuration folder:**

Open the Go menu in the OS X Finder
Hold the Option key and choose the Library option that appears
Move the “Safari” folder in here to your desktop

**Remove Safari’s window state:**

Open the Library > Saved Application State folder
Locate the “com.apple.Safari.savedState” folder
Move this folder to the trash

**Remove Safari’s application caches:**

Open the Library > Caches folder
Locate all folders that begin with “com.apple.Safari”
Move these folders to the trash.

**Remove Safari Cookies configurations:**

Open the Library > Cookies folder
Remove the file called “com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.binarycookies”

**Remove Safari’s preferences:**

Open the Library > Preferences folder
Remove any file that begins with “com.apple.Safari”

**Remove user plug-ins:**

Go to the Library > Internet Plug-Ins folder
Move all items from this folder to your Desktop (or elsewhere)

**Remove global plug-ins:**

Go to the Macintosh HD > Library > Internet plug-ins folder
Move all items out of this folder except the following plug-ins:

> Default Browser.plugin
>
> iPhotoPhotocast.plugin
>
> Quartz Composer.webplugin
>
> QuickTime Plugin.plugin

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a modified `hosts` file which redirects google to rack-search.
* Check your `/etc/hosts` with `cat /etc/hosts` from the terminal or,
* open it in a text editor (in Finder select Go -> Go to Folder, and enter /etc/ in the dialog. The folder /etc should be visible in the Finder. From there select the hosts file & control click on it. Select Open With and choose your editor.)

An unmodified hosts file looks like this:

```
##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

If you have any other entries below these lines, delete those and save the hosts file.
MacOS' default text editor TextEdit will not let you save this file, so use one like BBedit, TextMate, Sublime Text, or use a terminal based editor like vim, nano or emacs.

Comment: Just checked the Host Database and there was nothing extra in it.        Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try to flush your DNS cache. See: [How to Flush DNS Cache in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2008/03/21/how-to-flush-your-dns-cache-in-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score -1):

go to system preferences/ click profile/ then delete it. it'll say forced. just try clicking around that's what I did. like open the page all the way if you can and then yeah click around. it'll pop up are you sure to delete/remove and click yes and enter in your admin password. after that my homepage wasn't locked anymore.

Comment: It's not clear from your answer what the problem is and what to do to solve it.Try editing your answer to make it clearer what you are saying.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have a forward slash / at the end of the new homepage you entered in the preferences panel.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided is better than others already posted.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, evaluate the quality of your answer and provide up-votes for you.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review