# Safari 14.0 Homepage Hijacked

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I'm running a MacBook Air with Catalina 10.15.7 and Safari 14.0.  My homepage is DuckDuckGo but when I click on the homepage icon I get apple.com.  While the page is loading the URL is apple.com/startpage but the finished URL is just apple.com  I have no Profiles icon in System Preferences.  The homepage in System Preferences shows https://www.duckduckgo.com.  I have tried changing it but it goes back to duckduckgo and still opens with apple.com (BTW the apple.com page is an ad for iPhone 12).  This started 2 days ago.  I have used finder to search for numerous known adware sites but nothing has been found.

I am not a computer techie, but I can follow directions if anyone can lead me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.  A picture of my Safari preferences is included.  I have no extensions and have forced quit Safari with no positive results[image: Safari Preferences, General]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your Safari preferences showing that setup? The "apple.com" URL is normal as Safari "cleans things up" in the address bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is resolved but for now my homepage is working.  I'm not sure how to get a copy of the picture into here.

Comment: When you're editing your question, there's an image icon (mountains with sun/moon in a square box) that will allow you to upload or paste an image.

Comment: HIJACKING RESOLVED!  I'm not sure exactly what resolved the issue, but I followed the instructions at this link:      https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290543/safari-homepage-hijacked-and-i-cant-change-back      Nothing initially changed on my computer so I did a Force Quit of Safari and reopened it with the same apple.com page opening.  Following the instructions of the above link, I did not find any of the listed malware and/or adware on my computer.  I am unaware of what part of those instructions actually ended up resolving my problem, but THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad you’ve got a solution to your problem! I’ve linked this question to that question to help future visitors find the solution you did. Thanks for coming back to update your question.

Comment: I guess my issue is not resolved because the homepage is again going to apple.com even though my preference is set at duckduckgo.com.  Cannot find any solution to the problem.